# Load data error with data containing semi colon

Tags: php, mysql

Im using the following sql to import the data using "load data" of mysql. The description field contains semi colon, so the contents coming after semi colon is not inserting

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  '/tmp/phpz4m7Rl' INTO TABLE  `mytable` FIELDS TERMINATED BY  ';' ENCLOSED BY  '"' ESCAPED BY  '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY  '\n'
```

Actual data is given below

```
1;2;3;D;Testdata: Testing; 100% Perfect
```

But it is inserting only

```
1;2;3;D;Testdata: Testing;
```

My table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` text NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `product` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `language` text NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

What should I change to get the full data ?

Comment: @Salman A I reckon there isn't supposed to be one. I believe binoy wants to have the description column populated with "Testdata: Testing; 100% Perfect". However, since this string contains the semi-colon delimiter it is truncating the string to just "Testdata: Testing"

Comment: I am afraid you've ended up with a file that needs hand editing. You cannot import it into a spreadsheet either. If you're 100% sure that the `language` column does not contain `;` I can provide you a PHP script to fix the data. Will that be OK?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether the following are feasible but....

**Option 1 - Use a Different Delimiter**

you could change the field delimiter from a semi-colon to something like a tilde (~). So you would then have:

Data:

```
1~2~3~D~Testdata: Testing; 100% Perfect
```

Command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/phpz4m7Rl' INTO TABLE mytable FIELDS TERMINATED BY '~' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

**Option 2 - Enclose**

Or you could enclose the any data containing a semi-colon with speech marks:

Data

```
1;2;3;D;"Testdata: Testing; 100% Perfect"
```

And use your original command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/phpz4m7Rl' INTO TABLE mytable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

**Option 3 - Escape**

Or escape the problem semi-colon:

```
1;2;3;D;Testdata: Testing\; 100% Perfect
```

And use your original command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/phpz4m7Rl' INTO TABLE mytable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I need a code to handle all types of data, since I am getting the data from different people. is there any library to handle this ?